# Transformar diversas colunas em apenas uma

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-office

Olá, não programo VBA e não estou conseguindo fazer um código que fizesse o seguinte:

> ```
> |A |B |C |
> ----------
> |1 |6 |11|
> |2 |7 |12|
> |3 |8 |13|
> |4 |9 |14|
> |5 |10|15|
> ```

Minha tabela tem diversas colunas como essas ali em cima, gostaria que me ajudassem com uma rotina que iria ler a partir da coluna B e colocar sempre embaixo da coluna A, neste caso ficaria em sequência do 1 ao 15 na coluna A, isso é possível?

Resultado:

> ```
> |A  |
> -
> |1  |
> |2  |
> |3  |
> |4  |
> |5  |
> |6  |
> |7  |
> |...|
> |14 |
> |15 |
> ```

Comment: Quando voce diz tabela quer dizer uma planilha excel, vetores (arrays) ou é uma tabela do banco de dados access?

Comment: Uma tabela excel, gostaria de fazer uma macro para ela...

Answer (score 1):

Resposta do autor em comentário.

```
Sub macro()
    'Step 1:  Declare your variables.
        Dim MyRange As Range
        Dim MyCell As Range
        Dim i As Double
        i = 6000
    'Step 2:  Define the target Range.
        Set MyRange = Range("A1:T5917")
    'Step 3:  Start looping through the range.
        For Each MyCell In MyRange
    'Step 4:  Do something with each cell.
        MyCell.Cut
        Cells(i, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    'Step 5: Get the next cell in the range
        i = i + 1
        Next MyCell
End Sub
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Macro.vb).